# UIViewController View/Scene Transition Not Working Correctly in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have 10 UIViewControllers or Views in my game. All other view controllers are subclass of the first UIViewController, which in my case is ViewControllerA as shown below. I transition to my Main Menu view or scene using function "home" from every view or scene. I also create and add home button to view programmatically using function "createHomeButton" which is only part of first view controller so that is available in every view controller subclass.

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
// Create and add to the scene home button
func createHomeButton () {
    let imageButton = UIImage(named: "home_button")
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 680, y: 650, width: 120, height: 100))
    button.setImage(imageButton, for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(home(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}

// Dismiss current view controller and transition to Main Menu scene
func home(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    NSLog("Transition to Main Menu scene")
    let viewController = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
    viewController!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Then in my ViewControllerB and the rest of view controllers, which are all subclass of ViewcontrollerA, I don't create home button because I already created it in ViewControllerA which is now available for every subclass view.

```
class ViewControllerB: ViewControllerA {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
```

With this setup, when I'm in subclass ViewControllerB and I click on Home Button, it first transitions to ViewControllerA view then to the Main Menu view. Basically from every view controller subclass when that Home Button is pressed, I will transition to ViewControllerA view then to the Main Menu view.

Is there a way to have this setup such that when I'm in either subclass view controller to directly transition to Main Menu scene rather then going to first view then to the Main Menu scene?

Comment: Given that your button is labelled "Home", it sounds more like you need to implement unwind segues.

Comment: This is not a good solution approach as you propose with such setup. There are probably different options out there that some developers may be familiar with when it comes to view controller transitions. However, I do appreciate very much your response. Thanks.